# Write bash output to each directory the script executes

Tags: bash, awk

I have **N** directories each containing space delimited **.txt** file. I want to traverse through each directory and write a file based on column value inside each directory. Here is a case of two folders as example:

`folderA` has a file called **fileA.txt** and `folderB` has **fileB.txt**.

contents of **fileA.txt**

```
1 a
1 b
2 a
2 b
```

contents of **fileB.txt**

```
1 a
1 b
2 a
2 b
```

Desired output inside `folderA` and `folderB` is the same in this case; that is file named **1** and **2** based on contents of first column will be created inside both folders containing the lines

### **1** (file name)

```
1 a
1 b
```

### **2** (file name)

```
2 a
2 b
```

respectively.

What I did so far is below; and couldn't get to write the files (**1** & **2**) in their respective folders.

```
for file in ./*.txt; do

awk -F " " '{print>$1}' $file

done
```

I have tried a couple of options to fix the `print>$1` statement as that is where the redirection occurs; any concept help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `awk` for this?

Comment: Not really @CharlesDuffy

Comment: You *could* also run a [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) loop, though `awk` is actually a pretty good choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change into each subdirectory in a subshell before iterating over the files within:

```
#!/bin/bash

# configure the shell such that a glob with no matches returns zero results
shopt -s nullglob

# iterate over directories, starting a subshell for each
for dir in ./*/; do (
  # change directory within that subshell, or cause it to exit if that fails
  cd "$dir" || exit

  # ...and likewise, run awk in that subshell within the directory.
  # using "exec" is a performance optimization, consuming the subshell
  exec awk '{print>$1}' *.txt
); done
```

---

...or, even easier, let `find` (if you have one with the `-execdir` extension) do the work of running `awk` in each directory with at least one `.txt` file:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -execdir awk '{print>$1}' {} +
```

Comment: Works like a charm... Thank you so much.